# Azure Data Factory- Data Flow - After completion - move

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF v2 DataFlow ativity to load data from a csv file in a Blob Storage into a table in Azure SQL database. In the Dataflow (Source - Blob storage), in Source options, there is an option 'After Completion(No Action/Delete Source file/ Move)'. I am looking to utilize the move option to save those csv files in a container renaming those files in concatenation with with today's date. How do I frame the logic for this? Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi @Pranjal, do you have any other concerns? Please feel free to let me know. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the file name explicitly in both From and To-fields. This is not so well (if at all) documented, and I found it just  trying different approaches.

[image: Screenshot]

You can also add dynamic content such as timestamps. Here's an example:

```
concat('incoming/archive/', toString(currentUTC(), 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss_'), 'target_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parameter the source file to achieve that. Please ref my example.

Data Flow parameter settings:
[image]

Set the source file and move expression in **Source Options:**
[image]

Expressions to rename the source with "name + current date":

```
concat(substring($filename, 1, length($filename)-4),toString(currentUTC(),'yyyy-MM-dd') )
```

My full file name is "word.csv", the output file name is "word2020-01-26",
[image]

HTH.

Comment: how does this work when I use a wildcard expression? The documentation is still rather sparse.

Comment: @Bennimi I'm still stuck on this one where wildcards are used. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: never ever using DF again was my solution :D sorry